# Makefile implicit call g++

Tags: c++, makefile

I got a strange makefile from a tutorial on OpenGL:

```
LDLIBS=-lglut -lGLEW -lGL -lm
all: cube
clean:
        rm -f *.o cube
cube: shader_utils.o
.PHONY: all clean
```

The sources consist in 3 files: cube.cpp, shader_utils.h and shader_utils.cpp. I compile the project by doing "> make cube" but I don't understand the cube target and why is g++ called. I didn't specify to use g++ neither to use the flag LDLIBS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you observed is caused by the [GNU Make Implicit Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html). You can even do things like below (without having `Makefile` at all):

```
make -f /dev/null shader_utils.o
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are just defaults in gmake (a default rule to make .o from .cpp or .c). It is seldom applicable in real life though - most likely, you'd like to provide some arguments to g++.